# Angular2 Template mixins and helpers

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Is there any way to define helper functions to generate HTML code *before* compilation time?

For example, it would be nice to generate `<i class="icon icon-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></i>` from something like `<icon>hamburguer</icon>` but **without the overhead and performance impact of creating a component**, I just need it to be translated before template compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended to use `AOT` (ahead of time compilation) in production, this will put the overhead and performance impact with component creation to a minimum. To have what you want, you will need to create some dynamic component, which will add actually extra overhead to the process, and doesn't work (well) with `AOT`.

A fast directive would look like this:

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[jmIcon]',
   host: {
     'attr.aria-hidden': 'true'
   }
})
export class IconDirective {

   @Input()
   public jmIcon: string;

   @HostBinding('class')
   public get classList(): string {
      return 'icon icon-' + this.jmIcon;
   }

}
```

With this usage:

```
<i jmIcon="hamburger"></i>
```

Comment: What would be faster, a full component or a directive like `<i icon="hamburguer"></i>` that just adds the classes and the `aria-hidden` attribute?

Comment: I think these will hardly matter performance wise. Better would be to check which will resolve in more maintainable code. In this example, I would guess it's easier to just create a `[jmIcon]` directive (using a prefix is recommended).